# why does unordered_map not have rbegin() or rend(), but only begin() and end()

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, unordered-map

It seems weird to iterate through an `unordered_map`, with begin(), end() and a forward iterator.

If so, why does it not have rbegin(), rend() and bi-direction iterators too?
is there any technical reason?

Comment: On the plus side, you get local bucket iterators. Doesn't that make up for it?

Comment: Because that would enforce too heavy an impact on the storage requirement of a single element (like *billz* explains) for a feature not neccessary at all (like *juanchopanza* explains). But good question, of course.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Cite from `The C++ Standard Library`

> Reverse iterators let algorithms operate backward by switching the
>   call of an increment operator internally into a call of the decrement
>   operator, and vice versa. All containers with bidirectional iterators
>   or random-access iterators (all sequence containers except
>   forward_list and all associative containers) can create reverse
>   iterators via their member functions rbegin() and rend(). Since C++11,
>   the corresponding member functions returning read-only iterators,
>   crbegin() and crend(), are also provided.
>
> For forward_lists and unordered containers, no backward-iteration
>   interface (rbegin(), rend(), etc.) is provided. The reason is that the
>   implementation requires only singly linked lists to go through the
>   elements.

Comment: And in standardese: 23.5.4.1/1 Class template unordered_map overview: "The unordered_map class supports forward iterators". Forward iterators are not reversible.

Comment: Why does the unordered_map has a begin(),since it's unordered?

Comment: @choxsword Because the unordered_map still has the items stored in a iterable structure, meaning it has a beginning and an end, yet the order of the items in the structure may change with every addition of an item (removal does not invalidate iterators).

Answer (score 23):

It is unordered, so the order in which the iteration takes place is (or should be) unimportant.

Comment: If the order is unimportant, why are there begin() & end() iterators? Don't begin() & end()  imply there is order?

Comment: @PhiloRobotist my guess is that it is to be compatible with the other standard library containers.